# $\frac{N!}{N^n \cdot(N-n)!} = 1 + \mathcal O(N^{-1})$?

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{N!}{N^n \cdot(N-n)!} = 1 + \mathcal O(N^{-1})$$

It's not clear to me how this is true. This is from the derivation of the radial distribution function. I only got $\mathcal O(1)$. I tried L'hospital's rule on $n \to \infty$ such that

$$\lim(a_n+1/a_n)=1/N.$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is fixed and $N$ is large, then
$$
\frac{{N!}}{{N^n (N - n)!}} = \frac{{N(N - 1) \cdots (N - n + 1)}}{{N^n }} = \left( {1 - \frac{1}{N}} \right)\left( {1 - \frac{2}{N}} \right) \cdots \left( {1 - \frac{{n - 1}}{N}} \right) \\
 = 1 + \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {( - k)}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{N^2 }}} \right) = 1 - \frac{{n(n - 1)}}{{2N}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{N^2 }}} \right).
$$